# How to convert List<List<X>> to List<X> in RxAndroid?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I have list of ids and I am maping it to list of sublists so getting list> and then I need to get one list of items but  I don't know the proper operator for it.

```
.map { it ->
      val step = 200
      var count = it.stores.size
      val subLists = ArrayList<List<Int>>()
      var i = 1
      while (count > 0) {
        val start = (i - 1) * step
//if...
        var end = i * step
        count -= step
        val items = it.items.subList(start, end)
        subLists.add(items)
        i++
      }
      subLists
    }
    .toFlowable()
    .flatMapIterable { it -> it }
    .flatMap {
     personDao.loadById(it)
    }.toList()
```

.I need to get one list of items , how?

Comment: What should this one list contain? All of the id's of all of the lists?

Comment: Should be [flatMap](https://medium.com/@daveford/map-versup-flatmap-14780ab01d2b)/[flatmapIterable](https://medium.com/@ubuntudroid/rxjava-flattening-a-stream-of-iterables-ea26f593ba07).  Something like `.flatMap( it -> it.items)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just simply use:

```
val oldList: List<List<T>> = listOf()
val newList = oldList.flatMap { it }
```

And you don't have to use Rx for it

If you need Rx:

```
val flowable = Flowable.fromIterable(oldList).flatMap { 
        Flowable.fromIterable(it)
    }
```

And you get `Flowable<T>`

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer my question which I haven't thought well .so my answer use map and inside map go over list and it to list of Items

```
.map {
      var items = emptyList<Item>()
      it.map {
        items += it
      }
      items
    }.toFlowable()
```

Comment: It will return your nested list . 
.map{
var items = emptyList<Item>()
items =it.stores
}